# 'Get dependency" pop up not appearing, what is wrong with android studio?

Tags: android-studio, flutter

all code underlined in red android studio up to date, already re-installed project, all sdk tools up to date. What else have to be done?
[what my laptop showing right now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h7wwn.png)

[And what I want show my laptop should be like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/09GjR.png)

Comment: Never put images as urls, always show them directly as part of your question. Saves a lot of people a lot of extra clicks.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following command in terminal

> flutter pub get

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1:**
Open the `pubspec.yaml` filr from the left side project view and then click the `Pub Get`  text on top-right of the file. This will download all the dependencies and then your project should build.

**Option 2:** Open a command prompt, cd to your project root directory and then run the following command:

```
flutter pub get
```

This will also download the dependencies.